# Are quantitative questions off topic?

Tags: discussion

Physics.SE includes both qualitative and quantitative questions that relate to principles in physics, and does not send all of their quantitative questions off to Maths.SE.

On Earth Science, are we going to follow the path of physics.SE and allow quantitative questions on Earth science topics, like [this one](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/342/how-can-the-following-equation-for-meandering-rivers-be-theoretically-derived?noredirect=1#comment472_342), or should we just have the mathematicians deal with anything slightly quantitative on maths.SE, and stick with only qualitative conceptual questions here?

Comment: There are generally two types of math questions that come up in Earth Science. This question seems to be asking about the mathematics of physical theories. Yes? The other category is statistics. What about statistical techniques that are specific to Earth Sciences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think we should keep the quantitative on-topic questions here.  Many of the problems in meteorology are not going be handled by straight mathematics without some physics insight (e.g. knowing the full set of primitive equations and what they represent) as well as certain common approximations we use.

Certain problems like getting an general analytic solution to Navier-Stokes may be better posed in the realm of pure math, but thats not a problem you'll get an answer on here or at maths.SE.

Comment: I agree. This is science. How could quantitative questions possibly be off-topic?